# What Communication Protocol does Hyper Terminal Use?

Tags: protocols, communication, hyperterminal

I have a device which connects via serial port. I communicate with it via Windows Hyper Terminal. I'm just wondering, what protocol does it use? As you probably, know hyper terminal can display and accept input as well. It's a two way communication.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

HyperTerminal uses the following communication protocols [according to TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457166.aspx#ECAA):

> **Transmission protocol and port:** The protocols used are Kermit, Xmodem, Xmodem-1K, Ymodem, Ymodem-G and Zmodem transmissions protocols on port 23

Comment: The communication protocol to use is specified on the [connection properties](http://www.angelfire.com/mac/gregor49032/Files/winxptcr/winsock/1.htm#4) or when [transferring a file](http://www.angelfire.com/mac/gregor49032/Files/winxptcr/winsock/1.htm#6).

Comment: If HyperTerminal is used [as a Telnet client](http://www.angelfire.com/mac/gregor49032/Files/winxptcr/winsock/2.htm#2) then the protocol is specified on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no protocol. Serial sends and recieve bits. You specify them in your serial setting when you want to communicate with a device. Typically 8 bits are specified which is equivalent to an ASCII character. Both communicating parties send and receive ASCII data any time they want